# Page navigation won't show up for the Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I use PHP Code for post to place PHP into a template. Everything works fine, but the page navigation won't show up.

Here's a simple loop from my site. It was designed in `local host`, so I can't give you the address.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $lastest= new WP_Query ( array
    (
        'post_type' => post,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    )
    );
?>
<div id="content-wrap">
    <?php while($lastest->have_posts()) : $lastest->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="lastest-new-wrap">
        <div id="thumbnail-wrap">
            <div id="thumbnail-size"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <h1 id="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <div id="post-desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

---

Thx you for reply !
But the text link don't show . I mean Older post and New post
I'm using this php code to call it :

```
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

Note : First time , i use "Your latest posts" at Homepage . It show good but Paged is not right !

Second time , i use a Static Page for Homepage . Then the text link don't show up ! Do use know why ? I use PHP Code for Post to insert PHP Code in Page . Then I Design one unique Page named "HomePage" . Design this Page with
"WPBakery Visual Composer"

If u know how to fix it plz help me ! Thx so much

Comment: Where in this code are you expecting the navigation to show up?

Comment: After 10 Post Loop . And then it show up for next page . Like category !

Answer (score 2):

You are using custom query, so you need to add $paged parameter like this:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
<?php $lastest= new WP_Query ( array
    (
        'post_type' => post,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged
    )
    );
?>
```

Comment: One of the possible things. totally agreeing since It already resolved this issue for me in the past. +1